# Nuxt - prevent direct access to page directory url

Tags: nuxt.js

It's my Nuxt's page structure:

```
pages/
      users.vue
      users/
           login.vue
           register.vue
           forgot-password.vue
```

I have set layout and middleware in `users.vue` to be common in its sub pages.
I don't want anyone to direct access to `users` page url and when someone enter `example.com/users` , I expect it returns 404 error.
I only want it's sub pages to be accessible. (`example.com/users/login` & ...)
What can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

for best practice don't make direct url name first try this

```
pages/
      users/
           index.vue //this will your user.vue
           login
              index.vue
           register
              index.vue
           forgot-password
              index.vue
```

now make a middleware guest.js

guest.js

```
export default function({ app, redirect }) {
  if (app.$auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/');
  }
}
```

add this to login page

```
middleware: 'guest'
```

this will check if user already logged in redirect to `'/'` or you can edit route to any

nuxt auth module make default auth module

just use this to users page

```
middleware: 'auth'
```

or you can customize with make new middleware as name `auth.js`

```
export default function({ app, redirect }) {
  if (!app.$auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

lets take a look on 404 page

you can make static page like `/users` but best practice make dynamic route `/username`

so your data structure looks like this

```
pages/
      _username
         index.vue // Dynamic Route
      users/
           index.vue //this will your user.vue
           login
              index.vue
           register
              index.vue
           forgot-password
              index.vue
```

now in your _username page

```
<template></template>

<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ $axios, params, error }) {
    return $axios
      .get(`/user/${params.username}`)
      .then(res => {
        return { user: res.data.data };
      })
      .catch(e => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' });
      });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: is guest.js required for this? doesn't the default nuxt auth module do this behavior?

Comment: guest is important if user is already login so user should not see login page

Comment: The default nuxt-auth module (middleware) comes with this feature? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware.html -- "You can set auth option to guest in a specific component. When this middleware is enabled on a route and loggedIn is true user will be redirected to redirect.home route. (/ by default)"